# MySQL syntax error except it doesn't look like that

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

My question is about this query:

```
select x2.c from x2 
left join x1
join x3 
on x1.a=x2.c and x3.b=x2.d;
```

which is returning the 'Error Code 1064' ("You have an error in you SQL syntax(...)").

At first, it was "select x2.*(...)". So, since I wanted a LEFT JOIN from x2, I thought maybe selecting all followed by that left join was causing the error, but it wasn't the case.

Also, removing 'left' from 'left join' eliminates the error, so

```
select x2.c from x2 
join x1 
join x3 
on x1.a=x2.c and x3.b=x2.d;
```

works fine.

So, probably three questions here:

1. What could be causing this error?
2. Why is it returning a syntax error?
3. How can a join type cause a syntax error?

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE x1 (A int);
insert into x1 value (1);
insert into x1 value (2);
insert into x1 value (3);
insert into x1 value (4);
insert into x1 value (5);

CREATE TABLE x2 (C int, D int);
insert into x2 values (1,1);
insert into x2 values (1,3);
insert into x2 values (1,5);
insert into x2 values (2,1);
insert into x2 values (2,3);
insert into x2 values (3,1);
insert into x2 values (3,1);

CREATE TABLE x3 (B int);
insert into x3 value (1);
insert into x3 value (2);
insert into x3 value (3);
```

Comment: Your query is invalid.  You have `join`s without `on`.  (MySQL does allow that for inner join but not for outer joins).

Comment: You are absolutely right. My bad! But the error also occurs with "on". I will fix it right now.

Comment: the syntax is  `... from x2 left join x1 on x2.c = x1.a ...`. Ie the `LEFT JOIN` needs a join specification, the (inner) `JOIN` doesn't. Ie, you put the `ON` after the wrong join statement ...

Comment: Please, read the basic syntax of the join of SQL. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @jainvikram444 Please don't link to w3schools. If you want to link to docs, please refer to the official docs of the product ... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: @derpirscher: It's just for ref. You can learn from official https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: I actually did use ON correctly, but messed up while writing the query for this post(already fixed btw). The error came from not implementing the join specification, as mentioned by @derpirscher Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Do yourself a big favor, have one `ON` for each `JOIN`!

Answer (score 0):

JOIN - ON condition.  Not in the where clause

```
select 
      x2.c 
   from 
      x2 
         left join x1
            on x2.c = x1.a
         join x3 
            on x2.d = x3.b
```

Notice reading tables and relationships left to right.  I have the left alias.column = right alias.column for readability

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [syntax documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) we can see that `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins need an `ON` or a `USING`  clause:

```
joined_table: {
    table_reference {[INNER | CROSS] JOIN | STRAIGHT_JOIN} table_factor [join_specification]
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_specification
  | table_reference NATURAL [INNER | {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
}

join_specification: {
    ON search_condition
  | USING (join_column_list)
}
```

I guess such types of joins simply do not make sense without further column information.